# portfolio optimisation based on historical prices

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization

I'm hoping somebody can help me with the following problem (I'm not a quant).

I have a SQL table which contains the historic prices for 3 securities, x,y and z. It has the date and the price.  I have to a write a program that, for each year, outputs the buy/sell transactions necessary to maximise the value of the portfolio.  The portfolio has an initial fund of £20000.  yes this a test, but it's not homework.  I don't know where to begin, I don't need help with  the coding but I do need some assistance with the algorithm/math?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly you need to calculate logarithmic returns and then depends on the software you use. For instance `R` has everything already coded. If you want to to it yourself (recommended if you say programming is not an issue), then I found [this](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdifat8YHPAhWIVRQKHQkqDVQQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.washington.edu%2Fezivot%2Fecon424%2FportfolioTheoryMatrix.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEWs_-yM5P0LgHffSIVos8kJstC6w&sig2=P8HwK9mV-7ZtlSYkgfVO3A) quite straight forward and shows the code in `R` as well.

1) get the returns

2) calculate covariance matrix

3) optimise either to find a Global Minimum Variance portfolio, or minimum variance portfolio given a level of return. But then you are adding more uncertainty to the model as you don't really know what is the true expected return.

4) You will get your vector of weights and find returns of the portfolio. The weights are the transaction you need - if it is positive, you're buying, if negative you are selling the asset short.

If you need the returns in $, then sum up the logarithmic returns and transform them back by taking the exponential of them and subtract 1; you get the cumulative return at the end of the period

5) Follow the link, it walks you through it quite nicely in detail.. If you need anything else, comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write all the code yourself, you can you `R`, package `PortfolioAnalytics`.

It allows you to create portfolio (`portfolio.spec`), and optimization constraints (`add.constraint`) and set objectives (`add.objective`) and optimize it.

**Example code**

```
portfolio <- portfolio.spec(assets=fund.names)

portfolio <- add.constraint(portfolio , type="full_investment")
portfolio <- add.constraint(portfolio , type="long_only")

portfolio <- add.objective(portfolio, type="risk", name="var")

# monthly rebalancing, 2 year training, 2 year rolling:

portfolio.optimized <- optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(returns, portfolio,
ptimize_method="quadprog",
rebalance_on="months",
training_period=24,
rolling_window=24)
```

The package is quite flexible, you can add group constraints, long/short/box constraints; add objectives for risk minimizing, mean maximizing, quadratic utility maximizing etc; supports `quadprog` solver etc.
It also allows you to plugin your own covariance matrix (e.g. if you don't want to use `cov` but your own like robust covariance matrix estimate).
And has support for parallel processing.

Plenty of code samples in vignette:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/PortfolioAnalytics.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Unfortunately I can't use R, I have to do it in .NET.  The info/examples you provided are helpful.